# Lucene 6.2 and ISO-8859-1 (latin) characters

Tags: lucene, iso-8859-1

I'm trying Lucene index searcher on a project.

The content of the documents indexed have latin (ISO-8859-1) characters, so the users can (and will) also search using this charset.

As far as I know, Lucene generates the index files using UTF-8.

Questions:

**1)** Is there any way to specify the charset when searching with Lucene? Or will I have to manually convert the query to UTF-8 and then run the search?

**2)** The IndexSearcher.search() method is not ignoring whitespaces, so I have to guess the "tokens" right for any meaningful results to show up. If the user forgets to add the whitespaces on the searched term, then no results are showed. Is there any way to configure the searcher (or the QueryParser) to ignore whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

1. Not quite sure exactly where you are running into trouble here.  I would presume you are reading user input as a String, so I'm don't know where the issue would come up. Providing your code would probably clarify that. If you are, indeed, reading a byte array from user input, then yes, converting would be necessary.  It's not exactly a laborious process to convert a byte[] to a String though.  Just use the [String ctor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)).
2. QueryParser tokenizes at whitespace if the analyzer you have [passed it](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html#QueryParser-java.lang.String-org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer-) does.  `StandardAnalyzer` would be the typical choice.

Comment: 1. I'm not reading from a byte array and then converting, it's just Strings. But the user can search with characters like: "ãáéóíõ", etc. So I was just wondering if there's any option on the API to filter them correctly, because the index files generated ignored the accented characters. If there isn't one, I'll just keep with the old Normalizer to remove them before searching.

Comment: 2. Thank you, I'm already using it:

Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
   QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(field, analyzer);
   Query query = queryParser.parse(searchedValue);

But if the user forget to add the whitespaces on the searched term, then no results are returned.